# Is there any extension to manage ACL based on the multi-source-inventory?

Tags: magento2, admin, acl, multi-source-inventory

I have some requirements related to managing orders from the admin.
but different admin has separate inventory source.

Like source, A assigned to admin 1
and source B assigned to admin 2

then admin 1 only views order related to source A

So Is there any extension to manage ACL based on the inventory source?

Thanks in advance